# how to display the outputs by name

Tags: java

I have to read from a binary file and then I should display the output in order by name.

### The question :

Write a program that read data from a binary file person.dat. (Please download the binary file from the Web site.) Then, display the name, age and gender (M – Male, F – Female) in ascending order sort by name.

The structure of the binary file is as below:

> intVariable-TotalNumberofRecord
>
> StringVariable-Name IntVariable-Age CharVariable-Gender
>
> …
>
> StringVariable-Name IntVariable-Age CharVariable-Gender

### This is what in the binary file (person.dat)

> ¬í wa    Mohamad Ali    M Siti Nuraini    F Tan Mei Kuan    F
>     Mutu Samy    M  Alvin Tan    M

============================================

This is the code that I have made. The problem is I don't know how to sort the outputs in alphabetical order. Please help me with this, thank you.

```
    try {
        ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream (new FileInputStream("C:/Users/user/Desktop/person.dat"));

        String input;
        int age, record;
        char gender;

        record = inputStream.readInt();
        System.out.println("Total number of records: "+record);

           try{ 
              while(true) {
                input = inputStream.readUTF(); 
                age = inputStream.readInt(); 
                gender = inputStream.readChar(); 

                System.out.println(input+" " +age +" " +gender);}

           }catch(EOFException e){}

        inputStream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File was not found"); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Problem with file output.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To sort the data, you must first put the data into a collection (such as `ArrayList`), sort it, and then output.

Before you can put the data into a collection, you should create a `class` to hold the data together. It should be a very simple class that just accepts a name, an age, and a gender in a constructor.

To let instances of your class be sorted, make your class implement the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface. The `.compareTo` method can just call the same method of the names being compared.

I hope this is enough to make sense of the rest of your lecture notes.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement 9000's suggestion, I could create a `Person` class to serve as the record to be added to a sortable Java Collection (i.e. List, Set, etc).

```
public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private char gender

    public Person(String name, int age, char gender)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    // omitted getters and setters
}
```

Assuming you chose `List`, you can do something like this:

```
List<Person> records = new ArrayList<Person>();
records.add(new Person("Joe", 41, M));
records.add(new Person("Anne", 23, F));
records.add(new Person("Walter", 18, M));
...
```

Then, you can take advantage of the `Collections.sort()` function and sort it by the criteria you need, for example age (may not be totally accurate):

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Integer>()
{
    public int compare(Integer age1, Integer age2) {
        return (age1 > age2 ? -1 : (age1 == age2 ? 0 : 1));
    }
});
```

To be sure how to implement this correctly, I suggest to review this Java tutorial on [Object Ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) from the Oracle Java website.  You will probably need three types of `Comparators`: `NameComparator`, `AgeComparator`, and `GenderComparator`.  That way, you would be able to sort your records by name, by age, or by gender. Or, even better, you might be able to combine them, so that you could sort by name and age; for example.